# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference error

Tags: java, android

I'm new at coding and I am making simple flashlight android program in Android Studio. But I am getting this problem (shown in LogCat) and don't know how to resolve it.

I tried searching of this error in forums, tried debugging, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

The whole script

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FlashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonEnable;
    private ImageView imageFlashlight;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 50;
    private boolean flashLightStatus = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageFlashlight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageFlashlight);
        buttonEnable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnable);

        final boolean hasCameraFlash = getPackageManager().
                hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
        boolean isEnabled = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        buttonEnable.setEnabled(!isEnabled);
        imageFlashlight.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        buttonEnable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(FlashActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        imageFlashlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (hasCameraFlash) {
                    if (flashLightStatus)
                        flashLightOff();
                    else
                        flashLightOn();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(FlashActivity.this, "No flash available on your device",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void flashLightOn() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
            flashLightStatus = true;
            imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    private void flashLightOff() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
            flashLightStatus = false;
            imageFlashlight.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case CAMERA_REQUEST :
                if (grantResults.length > 0  &&  grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    buttonEnable.setEnabled(false);
                    buttonEnable.setText("Camera Enabled");
                    imageFlashlight.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(FlashActivity.this, "Permission Denied for the Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The error of Log Cat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: l.www.survivalbook, PID: 8117
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{l.www.survivalbook/l.www.survivalbook.FlashActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at l.www.survivalbook.FlashActivity.onCreate(FlashActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

the line, where error is shown (39 code line)

```
        buttonEnable.setEnabled(!isEnabled);
        imageFlashlight.setEnabled(isEnabled);
```

Here is xml script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_compass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="0°"
        android:id="@+id/txt_azimuth"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/kompasas"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_azimuth"
        android:id="@+id/img_compass"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml file.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are not the same thing.

Comment: There is no button in your entire view.

Answer (score 0):

A null object Reference always points out that there is some object in your code that has no value.

```
Button myButton = null;
myButton.setVisibility(GONE);
```

The code above will always lead to the error that appears in your code. Your buttonEnable has no value. Try `buttonEnable = new Button()` or use `findViewById` if you declared the button within your layout XML.